# Send Email to clients by collecting lists of orders between specific hours

Tags: java, cron, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I have a requirement where i need to send email to the clients based on Timeslots.

Scenario - Admin will be having the privilege of adding the timeslots like 4 AM , 9 AM , 10 PM.
User will create orders and then i need to collect all the orders between timeslots.

Example
 Orders generated between 4 Am to 9 Am - will be collecting the list of all orders and sending the mails to the respective receiver at 9 Am.
Orders generated between 9 Am to 10 Pm collecting the orders , sending mails at 10 Pm
 Orders generated between 10 Pm to next day 4 Am - collceting and sending mail at next day 4 Am.

This is how my scenario looks like.

I have implemented Quartz Scheduler but it seems it wont work.

Any suggestions please??
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create 3 jobs in Quartz Schedular lets say Jobs with names

1) 9_AM_Job  :  running every day at 9  AM

2) 10_PM_Job :  running every day at 10 PM

3) 4_AM_Job  :  running every day at 4  AM

Every job collect the list of all order between respective time and send to respective users. The implementation of all jobs will be the same but they query data with respective timestamps.

Cron Trigger for job running 9 AM everyday is  : `0 0 9 ? * *`

Cron Trigger for job running 10 PM everyday is : `0 0 22 ? * *`

Cron Trigger for job running 4 AM everyday is  : `0 0 4 ? * *`

Comment: My TimeSlots are dynamic.Admin can generate timeslots based on his/her needs.

Comment: @GauravMasand then you can delete the previous Job and create the new Job with requested time. you only have to pass the time when creating a new job.